# Add two tensors with different dimensions in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am basically trying to add two tensors in tensorflow, the crux is that they are of different lengths
`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `b = [1, 2, 3]` and am looking for a function that I am calling `tf.myadd` in the following

```
tf.myadd(a, b) = [2, 4, 6, 4, 5]
```

I have been looking into [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/broadcasting), yet this has not the expected behavior.

Comment: since `tf` has broadcasting as default, you will need to do post padding with zeros and then use tf.add to get what you need. check my answer for more details.

Comment: @mrk You can do it like this: first `paddings = tf.zeros([tf.shape(a)[0]-tf.shape(b)[0]],dtype=tf.int32)` and then `tf.add(a,tf.concat([b, paddings],0))`.

Comment: thanks that nicely complements the numpy solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadcasting is the default for all tensor operations in `tf`. In this case, you are trying to avoid broadcasting since the 2 tensors ((5,) and (3,)) are NOT broadcastable along the axis=0 by the standard [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). **So what you need is an element-wise addition without broadcasting.**

What you can do as in this case is use post-padding on the smaller array such that the two 1D tensors have the same shape and then add them elementwise over `axis=0`.

Like this -

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 2, 3]

b_pad = np.pad(b, (0,len(a)-len(b)))

tf.add(a,b_pad).numpy()
```

```
array([2, 4, 6, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```